# No leaning for communal offerings? But there is!

Tags: yom-kippur, korban, maseches-menachos

[*M'nachos* 9:9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Menachot.9.9):

> חֹמֶר בַּסְּמִיכָה מִבַּתְּנוּפָה וּבַתְּנוּפָה מִבַּסְּמִיכָה, שֶׁאֶחָד מֵנִיף לְכָל הַחֲבֵרִים וְאֵין אֶחָד סוֹמֵךְ לְכָל הַחֲבֵרִים. וְחֹמֶר בַּתְּנוּפָה, שֶׁהַתְּנוּפָה נוֹהֶגֶת בְּקָרְבְּנוֹת הַיָּחִיד וּבְקָרְבְּנוֹת הַצִּבּוּר, בַּחַיִּים וּבַשְּׁחוּטִין, בְּדָבָר שֶׁיֶּשׁ בּוֹ רוּחַ חַיִּים וּבְדָבָר שֶׁאֵין בּוֹ רוּחַ חַיִּים, מַה שֶּׁאֵין כֵּן בַּסְּמִיכָה.‏

> There's something more strict about leaning [on an offering] than about waving [an offering], and [something more strict] about waving than about leaning.… More strict about waving: that waving is practiced with personal and communal offerings…, which is not the case with leaning.

<sub>(The Hebrew text, including vowels and punctuation, is Sefaria's. The translation is mine.)</sub>

But waving is practiced with just two animals offered as a communal offering: the two *sh'lamim* sheep offered on *Shavuos*. And leaning is also practiced with two communal offerings: the goat sent to the wilderness on *Yom Kipur* and the *par heelem davar shel tzibur* (the bull offered when the community follows a national ruling and thereby violates any of certain commands). Granted the latter must have been extremely rare, but the goat was offered every year just like the *Shavuos* sheep, so how can the *mishna* say that leaning is not practiced with communal offerings but waving is?

Comment: +1 Although note that these are particularly unusual קרבנות צבור; no part of the שעיר המשתלח is offered up in the Temple, and the פר העלם דבר של צבור is not purchased using funds from the תרומת הלשכה

Answer (score 1):

That's because 2 Mishnayos back you already learned that these were exceptions.

[Menachot 9:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Menachot.9.7?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)

> כָּל קָרְבְּנוֹת הַצִּבּוּר אֵין בָּהֶם סְמִיכָה, חוּץ מִן הַפַּר הַבָּא עַל כָּל הַמִּצְוֹת, וְשָׂעִיר הַמִּשְׁתַּלֵּחַ. רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן אוֹמֵר, אַף שְׂעִירֵי עֲבוֹדָה זָרָה.:‏

> None of the communal offerings require the laying on of hands except the bull that is offered for [the transgression by the congregation] of any of the commandments, and the scapegoat. Rabbi Shimon says: also the he-goat offered for [the sin] of idol worship.

The reason for these being exceptions seems to be like [Joel K](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/14850/joel-k) explained in a comment:

> Although note that these are particularly unusual קרבנות צבור; no part of the שעיר המשתלח is offered up in the Temple, and the פר העלם דבר של צבור is not purchased using funds from the תרומת הלשכה

I.e. One of them is sacrificed **for** the community, but not **paid for by** the community, the other is not sacrificed in the Temple, hence they are not real communal offerings, as Mishna 7 explained, in anticipation of the rule in Mishna 9.

<sup>Actaully we *pasken* that each of the 12 tribes brings their own *par heelem davar shel tzibur*, after collecting the money from the entire tribe in a special "one off collection", and not from the communal coffers.</sup>

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. This _Mishna_ isn't saying "here's a list of things we lean on": it's saying "here's a stricture of waving over leaning". The fact that we already mentioned the leaned-on public offerings doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: @msh210 - clearer now?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, Danny Schoemann.

Comment: If I recall correctly, פר העלם דבר is paid for by the community, but a special one-off collection is made to pay for it

Comment: @JoelK - Correct. See the Peirush of the Rambam to Mishna 1:4 that we pasken that each tribe pays for their own, since each tribe brings their own, as per R' Yehuda. I've added that into the answer, as it highlights another difference. Thanks.